# Calling PeerGroupCreateInvitation from C#

Tags: c#, p2p, peer, invitation

Function description [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I'm struggling to get it right to call this function from c#.
I'm at a stage where I'm calling it but it's returning E_INVALIDARG.

I've set it up as follows...

```
[DllImport("p2p.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern uint PeerGroupCreateInvitation(IntPtr hGroup, string pwzIdentityInfo, IntPtr pftExpiration, int cRoles, IntPtr pRoles, out string ppwzInvitation);
```

My best guess is the 5th parameter, "pRoles".
I'm supposed to send it a pointer to one or two GUIDs representing the role type.

```
PEER_GROUP_ROLE_ADMIN
PEER_GROUP_ROLE_MEMBER
```

I have no clue presently how to do this from c#.

In C this parameter looks like this when calling the function...

```
..., (PEER_ROLE_ID*) &PEER_GROUP_ROLE_MEMBER, ...
```

PEER_ROLE_ID looks like a System.Guid type.
PEER_GROUP_ROLE_MEMBER looks like the actual GUID. (Can I get this from the p2p.dll file?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated... especially since there's close to ZERO info on this function on the internet.

**Working solution after everyone's comments.**

Declaration:

```
[DllImport("p2p.dll")]
public static extern uint PeerGroupCreateInvitation(IntPtr hGroup, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string pwzIdentityInfo, int pftExpiration, int cRoles, ref Guid pRoles, out IntPtr ppwzInvitation);
```

Calling:

```
uint hr = PeerGroupCreateInvitation(hGroup, identityInfo, 0, 1, ref PEER_GROUP_ROLE_MEMBER, out pInvitation);
```

...where PEER_GROUP_ROLE_MEMBER is the System.Guid for this role.

Getting the invitation:

```
string invitation = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pInvitation);
```

Comment: are you setting cRoles to the number of pRole guids? And shouldn't the pRoles just be a list of integers to represent the guids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct declaration:

```
[DllImport("p2p.dll")] 
public static extern uint PeerGroupCreateInvitation( 
                IntPtr hGroup,  /* Updated with @RedDude's suggestion */
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string pwzIdentityInfo, 
                int pftExpiration, // 32 bit, not 64 bit 
                int cRoles, 
                ref Guid pRoles, 
                out IntPtr ppwzInvitation);
```

Comment: pwzIdentityInfo should not be marshaled as a BSTR. BSTR is a length prefixed unicode string, the function signature indicates that it is expecting a null terminated unicode string.

Comment: @sternr Dead on the money! I made one change to your declaration, "IntPtr hGroup" rather than "int hGroup".

Comment: @Chris, I tried removing "[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]" and it breaks without it.

Answer (score 0):

As @strenr has said you should use a `ref Guid` argument to pass the GUID for the pRoles. However, and you might have already decided against this, have you taken a look at the WCF peer-to-peer support? This would give you most of the peer-to-peer capabilities already wrapped up in a .NET interface?

Take a look here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris. I started with the .NET p2p stuff but it just wasn't as "full blown" as whats in the p2p.dll. Will definitely look into it again though as those were just my initial thoughts.